# how to replace my dictionary key with my key-value pair if that contains " : " at the end of the string

Tags: json, python-3.x

If my key-value pair contains ": " at the end of the string. I want to replace my key with this matched string

```
input : ( from a text file)
```

I have converted each individual line to list of strings and I am passing these individual lines to my code (shown below)

I have written a regex to identify line which ends with " : "

```
#To identify line ending with ":"
regex = r".*[:]"
```

This is the input data

```
I am Playing cricket.
(a) true.
(b) false.
I am singing.
(a) true.
(b) false.
Furthermore, the heading does not include: 
(a) Singlets.
(b) fabrics.
(c) Smocks.
```

After converting text file to list of string:

```
plaintxtlist=['I am Playing cricket.','(a) true.','(b) false.','Furthermore, the heading does not include:','(a) Singlets.',' (b) fabrics.','(c) Smocks.']
```

The output from the code below:

All my first key value pair are my key here.

```
{'I am Playing cricket.': ['(a) true.', '(b) false.'],'I am singing.': ['(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 'Furthermore, the heading does not include:': ['(a) Singlets.', '(b) fabrics.', '(c) Smocks.']}
```

```
Code tried by me

import re
data = {} #dictonary 
lst = []    #list
regalter=r"^\s*\(([^\)]+)\).*|^\s*\-.*"   #regex to identify (a)(A) or - type of lines 
j=0
sub = [] #list
plaintxtlist=['Playing cricket is my hobby:','(a) true.','(b) false.','Furthermore, the heading does not include:','(a) Singlets.',' (b) fabrics.','(c) Smocks.']
for i in plaintxtlist:                #the data in text files are converted to list of strings and passed to code 
    if sub:
        match = re.match(regalter, i)   # pattern matching using regex
        if match:
            sub.append(i)             #if the line containes (a)or(A) it will be appended to list called sub
        else:
            j=j+1                  #each list of lines will have value from 0 n (n is the last line) 
            sub = [i]              #list of text will be appended to list called sub
        data[str(j)] = sub         # here the sub list will be added to dictonary named data with o,1,2,3 respectively we are laster converting that to string      
    else:
        if sub:
            data[str(j)] = sub  #else if sub the content in the sublist will be appended to dictonary named data 
        sub = [i]                   #each line will be appended to sub list
        data[str(j)] = i           # if there is no match with regex the pain text will be appended to dictonary 
print(data)                         #print the
```

Current code help by "Sean_Syue"

```
#regular expression
import re

#text file containing my input data
with open('a_text_file.txt') as f:
   s = f.read()

#regular expression 
pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\s\().:,]+?\.(?!\n\()')
data = dict()

for m in re.findall(pattern, s):

    # Group the raw content by `regex`,
    group = m.strip()
    lst = group.split('\n')           # and fit each line into a list      

    # Strip out spaces in `key` and `value`
    key = lst[0].strip()
    value = [i.strip() for i in lst[1:]]     #first strip

    # Fit into the final output
    data.update({key: value})

print(data)  #printing my dictonary
```

The output i required :

```
#if There is no colen ":" in the string key value should be interger. If it contains colen that should be its key .          
{'0': ['I am Playing cricket.','(a) true.', '(b) false.'],'1': ['I am singing.','(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 'Furthermore, the heading does not include:': ['(a) Singlets.', '(b) fabrics.', '(c) Smocks.']}
```

Current output 
[image]

Required output 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find no need to use regex to match, [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function is what you need.
This is my implementation let me know if it misses something 
**OPTION 1**

```
plaintxtlist=[
    'I am Playing cricket.','(a) true.','(b) false.',
    'I am singing.' ,'(a) true.','(b) false.',
    'Furthermore, the heading does not include:','(a) Singlets.',' (b) fabrics.','(c) Smocks.']

required = {}
for item in plaintxtlist:
    item = item.strip()  # to remove trailing whitespaces
    if item.startswith('('): # if it starts with ( it must be an option
        required[list(required.keys())[-1]].append(item) # add option to the right key
    else:                # else its a label
        required[item]=[] # insert the label as key with an empty list

print(required)
```

Its output

```
{'I am Playing cricket.': ['(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 'I am singing.': ['(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 'Furthermore, the heading does not include:': ['(a) Singlets.', '(b) fabrics.', '(c) Smocks.']}
```

Output in console
[image]

**OPTION TWO** 
If you want to add more complexity so that **integer becomes key where there is no** **:** then you just need to twist things a little to.

```
plaintxtlist=[
    'I am Playing cricket.','(a) true.','(b) false.',
    'I am singing.' ,'(a) true.','(b) false.',
    'Furthermore, the heading does not include:','(a) Singlets.',' (b) fabrics.','(c) Smocks.']

required = {}
counter = 0
for item in plaintxtlist:
    item = item.strip()  # to remove trailing whitespaces
    if item.startswith('('): # if it starts with ( it must be an option
        required[list(required.keys())[-1]].append(item) # add option to the correct key
    else:                # else its a label
        if item.endswith(':'):
            required[item]=[] # insert the label as key with an empty list
        else:
            required[counter]=[]
            required[list(required.keys())[-1]].append(item) # add label and option to the list of the key        
        counter +=1  # keeps track of current map items so as to insert the right index as key
print(required) # just printing
```

so that output becomes

```
{0: ['I am Playing cricket.', '(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 1: ['I am singing.', '(a) true.', '(b) false.'], 'Furthermore, the heading does not include:': ['(a) Singlets.', '(b) fabrics.', '(c) Smocks.']}
```